# How to display or list the contents of the Mirth GlobalMap objects

Tags: javascript, hl7, mirth

Is there a method/function available in Mirth Connect that will list or output the contents of the Global Map? I would like both the 'key' and the value of the key.

Answer (score 4):

Following code will print the key as well as value of global map variable in mirth

```
 for each(key in globalMap.getVariables().keySet().toArray())
 logger.info(key + ': ' + globalMap.get(key));
```

Answer (score 2):

**put** ing the global map didn't work for me..
something like this in a javascript transformer anywhere in the channel will get you a listing of everything available to you in each scope, after a message has been processed, in the Mappings tab:

`for each(variable in responseMap)`
     `channelMap.put('R_' + variable.toString(),variable);`
 `for each (variable in channelMap)`
     `channelMap.put('C_' + variable.toString(),variable);`
`for each (variable in globalMap)`
     `channelMap.put('G_' + variable.toString(),variable);`

Answer (score 0):

Clumsy, but stick it in the channel map, and you can view it by looking at the Mapping tab when viewing a message (via dashboard).

```
channelMap.put('globalMap', globalMap);
```